Exclude subfolder from protected folders
Is there a way to exclude some subfolders from protected folders in Windows Security?
I added my One Drive folder as a protected folder, but I would like to exclude some subfolders from protection - Desktop as a lot of apps create a shortcut there, some folders where various apps create a backup or use it to store media files, ...
I know I can give access to some apps, but that's not what I would really want to do.

Consider adding a symlink to a folder, that is outside of the protected zone.

I will try, thanks.
